# mod_rewrite file exists and regex condition together

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a rewrite directing requests from dir/ to dir/app/webroot/

The problem is, in dir/app/webroot I have the following condition:

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

This is saying the files don't exist creating an endless loop because it can't find index.php.  I believe the problem is it is searching for dir/app/webroot/**dir**/index.php instead of dir/app/webroot/index.php in the !-f condition.

How can I manipulate the URI in the condition with a regex like: ^dir/(.*)$ so I can use only page (what is after dir/) to correct the path?

What I have so far is:

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/dir/(.*)$ [NC]
 RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/dir/app/webroot/%1 !-f
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

This fixed the endless loop but now it is always redirecting to index.php.   Do you see where I made a mistake?

Answer (score 1):

If the file is located in `webroot`, then it won't look in `webroot/dir` - it simply has no reason to.

I've tested with the following files, and it seems to work for me:

**`/dir/.htaccess`:**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /dir/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/dir/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app/webroot/$1 [L]
```

**`/dir/app/webroot/.htaccess`:**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /dir/app/webroot/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: Yes, thank you for confirming.  Using the trace4 log level, I can see the issue is elsewhere.